# Convert a date format in epoch

Tags: java, datetime, date, epoch

I have a string with a date format such as

```
Jun 13 2003 23:11:52.454 UTC
```

containing millisec... which I want to convert in epoch. 
Is there an utility in Java I can use to do this conversion?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

This code shows how to use a [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse a [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) from a String:

```
String str = "Jun 13 2003 23:11:52.454 UTC";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");
Date date = df.parse(str);
long epoch = date.getTime();
System.out.println(epoch); // 1055545912454
```

`Date.getTime()` returns the epoch time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 32):

You can also use the Java 8 API

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class StackoverflowTest{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String strDate = "Jun 13 2003 23:11:52.454 UTC";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");
        ZonedDateTime     zdt  = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDate,dtf);        
        System.out.println(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());  // 1055545912454  
    }
}
```

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class replaces the old [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You can then create a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) from which you can extract the desired epoch time.

The main advantage is that you are now thread safe.

Thanks to Basil Bourque for his remarks and suggestions. Read his answer for full details.

Answer (score 16):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.parse( 
                        "Jun 13 2003 23:11:52.454 UTC" , 
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "MMM d uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSS z" ) 
                    )
              .toInstant()
              .toEpochMilli()
```

> 1055545912454

## java.time

This Answer expands on the [Answer by Lockni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30830088/642706).

### `DateTimeFormatter`

First define a formatting pattern to match your input string by creating a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object.

```
String input = "Jun 13 2003 23:11:52.454 UTC";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "MMM d uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSS z" );
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Parse the string as a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). You can think of that class as: ( `Instant` + `ZoneId` ).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( "Jun 13 2003 23:11:52.454 UTC" , f );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2003-06-13T23:11:52.454Z[UTC]

[image: Table of types of date-time classes in modern java.time versus legacy.]

### Count-from-epoch

I do not recommend tracking date-time values as a count-from-[epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). Doing so makes debugging tricky as humans cannot discern a meaningful date-time from a number so invalid/unexpected values may slip by. Also such counts are ambiguous, in granularity (whole seconds, milli, micro, nano, etc.) and in epoch (at least two dozen in by various computer systems).

But if you insist you can get a count of milliseconds from the epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00`) through the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. Be aware this means data-loss as you are truncating any nanoseconds to milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant ();
```

> instant.toString(): 2003-06-13T23:11:52.454Z

```
long millisSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

> 1055545912454

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

### Unfortunately,

the solution provided in all existing answers will fail if you run them on a system with Non-English `Locale` because the given date-time string is in an English. [Never use `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter` without a `Locale`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573) as they are `Locale`-sensitive.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6687502/10819573) uses legacy date-time API which was the correct thing to do using the standard library in 2011 when the question was asked. In March 2014, `java.time` API supplanted the [error-prone legacy date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Since then, it has been strongly recommended to use this modern date-time API.

**Demo using java.time API**:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long epochMillis = ZonedDateTime.parse(
                    "Jun 13 2003 23:11:52.454 UTC",
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                        "MMM d uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSS z",
                        Locale.ENGLISH
                    )
                )
                .toInstant()
                .toEpochMilli();
        System.out.println(epochMillis);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
1055545912454
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: "Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale as they are Locale-sensitive." - this deserves an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

**Create Common Method to Convert String to Date format**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long test = ConvertStringToDate("May 26 10:41:23", "MMM dd hh:mm:ss");
    long test2 = ConvertStringToDate("Tue, Jun 06 2017, 12:30 AM", "EEE, MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm a");
    long test3 = ConvertStringToDate("Jun 13 2003 23:11:52.454 UTC", "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");
}

private static long ConvertStringToDate(String dateString, String format) {
    try {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(dateString).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don’t swallow exceptions. They have a meaning. Usually an important one.

Comment: I recommend staying away from the now long outdated date and time classes like `SimpleDateFormat`. In 2011, when the question was asked, I used them too. Not any more.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String dateTime="15-3-2019 09:50 AM" //time should be two digit like 08,09,10 
   DateTimeFormatter dtf  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a");
        LocalDateTime zdt  = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime,dtf);
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
        ZoneOffset zoneOffSet = zone.getRules().getOffset(now);
        long a= zdt.toInstant(zoneOffSet).toEpochMilli();
        Log.d("time","---"+a);
```

you can get zone id form this  [a link](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids/)!

Comment: Thank you for wanting to contribute. It’s not exactly the same question. I get `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '15-3-2019 09:50 AM' could not be parsed at index 3`. Finally the correct conversion is `long a = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, dtf).atZone(zone).toInstant().toEpochMilli();`.