# How to store RSS feeds in Android?

Tags: android, rss, android-sqlite

I want to cache RSS feeds into SQLite database to improve performance of the app.
I am only concerned with the very basic of the RSS feed namely the `title`, `description`, URL `guid` and the `pubDate`. As of now, I can process them and store them into `Vector<Feed>` where `Feed` is my custom class.

There area few things which I find mind-boggling as a newbie to Android.
Say I have feed items whose titles are as below:

```
1. Cat Kills the Dog
2. Curosity Killed the Cat in Revenge
3. Y U NO leave Cat alone ?
```

In the first run, getting the row count of the table will return zero which means that I have to add **all** the feeds into the database. No problems.
The problem comes when the feeds are updated. Here is the updated feed:

```
*. Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog. Dog Dies.
1. Cat Kills the Dog
2. Curosity Killed the Cat in Revenge
3. Y U NO leave Cat alone ?
```

The logic is:
1. Start parsing the RSS feeds.
2. Read the title of the newly fetched RSS feed.
3. Does it match the title of the first row of the data base?
3.1. No, then keep parsing and add this feed to the database.
3.2. Yes, then stop parsing and add this feed to the database.

Problem is, the row added now will be the **LAST ROW** of the table while it should be, as in the RSS XML feed, the first row so that subsequent comparison becomes easier.

The thing is to maintain the order of rows similar to that in the feed XML.
How do I maintain that order ?

Or, is there a better way to organize and store the feeds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, do not rely on the titles being unique. Instead, use the `guid` field which is meant to be the unique identifier for the item (see [the RSS specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html)).

**Updating feed**

Go through each item in the retrieved feed and see if the `guid` already exists in the database, if so, skip it.

If it does not exist, create an entry.

So, revising your logic:

1. Start parsing the RSS feeds.
2. Read the `guid` of the newly fetched RSS feed.
3. Does it match the `guid` of any row in the database?
   3.1. No, then keep parsing and add this feed to the database.
   3.2. Yes, then stop parsing and add this feed to the database.

**Order of the items**

There is also a field called `pubDate` which indicates when the item was published. Simply store the `pubDate` for each item in the database and use it in an `ORDER BY` clause when retrieveing:

`SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY pubDate DESC`

That will give you the items in order of original publication.

*UPDATE*: Since SQLite does not have a native data type for dates, you could either utilize [the time/date helper functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) or [convert `pubDate` to epoch format in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687433/convert-date-format-to-epoch) before you insert it into the database.

Comment: `pubDate` comes in this format `Fri, 09 Aug 2013 22:46:12` Do I directly store it in the table ?

Comment: Apparently SQLite stores dates as TEXT (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). The easiest way would be to store the `pubDate`as an INTEGER and convert it to UNIX epoch (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687433/convert-date-format-to-epoch).

Comment: And the reverse process at the time of retrieval so that I can convert to `Feed` objects ?? :)

Comment: @LittleChild http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535004/unix-epoch-time-to-java-date-object

Comment: Another situation is where the parsing of feeds stops abruptly either because user pressed stop or because the internet connection was loss. Say only 60 / 100 feeds were processed.
How do I manage that ? One is to maintain another table that knows whether errors occurred or not

Comment: @LittleChild You might want to look into transactions in SQLite (http://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html): " All changes within a single transaction in SQLite either occur completely or not at all, even if the act of writing the change out to the disk is interrupted by

a program crash,
an operating system crash, or
a power failure."

Comment: NO, not that !! My app has the option whereby the user can stop processing the feeds in which case he/she will only see the processed feeds on the screen. :)

Comment: Then start a transaction each item you do an `INSERT` and it will "clean up" if the user pressed quit before that `INSERT` was complete.

Comment: The thing is , how do I keep track of where the user cancelled ? :)

Comment: If you only add items where the `guid` does not already exist (as suggested), there is no need to keep track.