# Converting number only string into LocalDateTime

Tags: java, localdatetime

I have searched online but couldn't really find the way to do it as I hope.

My data look like "20201005114527", "20201002173838" .......

and would like to convert them into LocalDateTime.

It will be converted into json again afterwards.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "xxx/xxx") 
private LocalDateTime xxxxxDate;
```

But I'm just confused of converting those "number-only strings" into LocalDateTime.

Comment: Do you just want to convert the string **20201005114527** to an instance of `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: Unless you are using the time for "Booking appointments", use ZonedDateTime ot Instant instead for regular buisness apps for storing a record. More explaination can be found here. see answer with 900+ upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime

Comment: Like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58770498/5772882).

Answer (score 2):

Use the format mask `yyyyMMddHHmmss`?

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyyMMddHHmmss")
private LocalDateTime xxxxxDate;
```

Comment: That part is done by my co-worker and can't be changed..

Comment: I don't see any other obvious workaround here.  If the format of some of the data doesn't match the current mask in the annotation, then the mask needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a date-time string containing only digits isn’t any different from parsing a date-time string in any other format.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss");
    String numberOnlyString = "20201005114527";
    LocalDateTime xxxxxDate = LocalDateTime.parse(numberOnlyString, formatter);
    System.out.println(xxxxxDate);
```

Output:

> 2020-10-05T11:45:27