# Convert Date String into Epoch in Java

Tags: java, epoch, apache-commons-dateutils

Is there a way to convert a given `Date` String into `Milliseconds` (`Epoch` Long format) in java? Example : I want to convert

```
public static final String date = "04/28/2016";
```

into milliseconds (epoch).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687433/convert-date-format-to-epoch

Comment: yes, but first you need to parse your `String` as `Date` and then call `getTime()` on it.

Answer (score 15):

The getTime() method of the Date class returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getTime() from the type Date`, so I had to use `new Date().getTime()` instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply parse it to java.util.Date using java.text.SimpleDateFormat and call it's getTime() function. It will return the number of milliseconds since Jan 01 1970.

```
public static final String strDate = "04/28/2016";
try {
    Long millis = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(strDate).getTime();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: does parse work on date object?

Comment: `Date d = SimpleDateFormat(String pattern).parse(String strDate);`
It parses a string (formatted date) by a pattern specified and returns a `java.util.Date` object.

Comment: [Specified in Java8SE Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-)

Comment: Right. That was my understanding too. But the snippet in the answer confused me as there were no mention that date was a String

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that. I have edited the answer and renamed the variable to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Calendar` object and then set it's date to the date you want and then call its `getTimeInMillis()` method.

```
Calendar c = new Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2016, 3, 28);
c.getTimeInMillis();
```

If you want to convert the `String` directly into the date you can try this:

```
String date = "4/28/2016";
String[] dateSplit = date.split("/");
c.set(Integer.valueOf(dateSplit[2]), Integer.valueOf(dateSplit[0]) - 1, Integer.valueOf(dateSplit[1]));
c.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Warning in the Calendar class, the month starts from 0 so April is 3 not 4

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Calendar instance for getting millisecond from epoch

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    java.util.Date d = sdf.parse("04/28/2016");
    /*
     * Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.
     */
    System.out.println(d.getTime());
    //OR
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2016, 3, 28);
    //the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch.
    System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```