# Getting milliseconds from Date Time Android

Tags: android, date, parsing, time, timezone

I am developing an Android application in that I wants to get Millisecond from Date-Time.

I am using below code for the parsing but I can't get proper result.

```
public static long getTimeInMillisecond(String time) {
    // eg.  time = "27 Sep 2016 12:24PM";
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd MMM yyyy hh:mma");

    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

    try {
        Date mDate = sdf.parse(time);
        long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
        return timeInMilliseconds;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a date format in epoch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687433/convert-a-date-format-in-epoch)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static long getDateStringToLong(String str_date) {
        DateFormat formatter;
        Date date = null;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        try {
            date = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date.getTime();
    }
```

change date format as per your requirement
Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try to this code..

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");    
 String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());        
 Log.e("Log","Time----"+currentDateandTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution:

Adding **Locale.English** with **SimpleDateFormat** and working fine.

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd MMM yyyy hh:mma", Locale.ENGLISH);
```