# Java - SimpleDateFormat formatter to return epoch time with milliseconds

Tags: java, date, datetime, timestamp, epoch

I am very new to Java and coding in general - I have some code which returns a timestamp in the following format `yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ms` which is shown below:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:sss");
```

This returns:

```
2017.07.19 11:42:30:423
```

Is there a way to edit the "SimpleDateFormat formatter" code above to return the date/time as an epoch timestamp that includes milliseconds so that the value returned is formatted as per the below?

```
1500464550423
```

I'm hoping that I can amend the `("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:sss")` part of the `SimpleDateFormat formatter` code to do this.

Comment: It’s not 100 % clear to me. Are you saying that you are receiving `2017.07.19 11:42:30:423` as a string and you want to convert it to number of milliseconds since the epoch?

Comment: Thats right - the timestamp value is being used later in the code and is used to make a string of variables - the part that returns the timestamp is "+formatter.format(time)" without the quotes - this is why I was hoping that I could amend the ("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:sss")  part of the code to return the epoc in milliseconds as I am not sure how to amend the code to use the other methods people have suggested here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a simple error in the use of case in your format pattern string (these are case sensitive). And worse, you are using the old and troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. One of the many problems with it is it’s not telling you what the problem is.

So I recommend you use the modern Java date and time API instead (I am deliberately using your format pattern string verbatim):

```
    String receivedTimetamp = "2017.07.19 11:42:30:423";
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:sss");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(receivedTimetamp, parseFormatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

This code throws an `IllegalArgumentException: Too many pattern letters: s`. I hope this calls your awareness to the fact that you are using two s’s for seconds and three s’s for fraction of second. If it still isn’t clear, [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) will tell you that lowercase `s` is correct for seconds, while you need uppercase `S` for the fraction. Let’s repair:

```
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
```

Now the code prints `2017-07-19T11:42:30.423`, so we have managed to parse the string correctly.

To convert to milliseconds we are still missing a crucial piece of information: in what time zone should the timestamp be interpreted? I think the two obvious guesses are UTC and your local time zone (which I don’t know). Try UTC:

```
    System.out.println(dateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

This produces `1500464550423`, which is the number you asked for. I suppose we’re done.

If you wanted your JVM’s time zone setting instead, use `.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())` instead of `.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)`, but beware that the setting may be altered by other software running in the same JVM, so this is fragile.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation - I am struggling to understand how I can integrate this into my code as I am very new to Java, however I don't doubt what you have suggested is correct - I will need to spend some time to work this out

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check the [documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The pattern that corresponds to **milliseconds** is an **uppercase** `S`, while the **lowercase** `s` corresponds to **seconds**. The problem is that `SimpleDateFormat` usually doesn't complain and try to parse `423` as seconds, adding this amount to your end date (giving an incorrect result).

Anyway, `SimpleDateFormat` just parses a `String` to a `java.util.Date` or formats the `Date` to a `String`. If you want the epoch millis value, you must get it from the `Date` object:

```
// input string
String s = "2017.07.19 11:42:30:423";
// use correct format ('S' for milliseconds)
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
// parse to a date
Date date = formatter.parse(s);
// get epoch millis
long millis = date.getTime();
System.out.println(millis); // 1500475350423
```

The problem is that `SimpleDateFormat` uses the system's default timezone, so the final value above (`1500475350423`) will be equivalent to the specificed date and time in my system's timezone (which can be different from yours - just for the record, my system's default timezone is `America/Sao_Paulo`). If you want to specify in what timezone this date is, you need to set in the formatter (before calling `parse`):

```
// set a timezone to the formatter (using UTC as example)
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

With this, the result for `millis` will be `1500464550423` (the equivalent to the specificed date and time in UTC).

To do the opposite (create a date from the millis value), you must create a `Date` object and then pass it to the formatter (also taking care of setting a timezone to the formatter):

```
// create date from millis
Date date = new Date(1500464550423L);
// use correct format ('S' for milliseconds)
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
// format date
String formatted = formatter.format(date);
```

---

## Java new date/time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

As the input `String` has no timezone information (only date and time), first I parsed it to a `LocalDateTime` (a class that represents a date and time without timezone). Then I convert this date/time to a specific timezone and get the millis value from it:

```
// input string
String s = "2017.07.19 11:42:30:423";
// use correct format ('S' for milliseconds)
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
// as the input string has no timezone information, parse it to a LocalDateTime
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(s, formatter);

// convert the LocalDateTime to a timezone
ZonedDateTime zdt = dt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
// get the millis value
long millis = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli(); // 1500460950423
```

The value is now `1500460950423`, equivalent to the specified date and time in London timezone.

Note that the API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

You can also use `ZoneOffset.UTC` constant if you want to use UTC.

To do the opposite, you can get the millis value to create an Instant, convert it to a timezone and pass it to the formatter:

```
// create Instant from millis value 
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1500460950423L);
// use correct format ('S' for milliseconds)
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
// convert to timezone
ZonedDateTime z = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
// format
String formatted = z.format(formatter);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `java.util.Date` then invoking `getTime()` will return the number of millis since the epoch. For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:sss");

Date dateToBeFormatted = new Date();

// this will print a datetime literal on the above format
System.out.println(formatter.format(dateToBeFormatted));

// this will print the number of millis since the Java epoch
System.out.println(dateToBeFormatted.getTime());
```

The key point here is that in order to get the number of millis since the epoch you do not need a `SimpleDateFormatter` because the number of millis since the epoch is a property of the `Date`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - the code I reference above is part of a block of code and I am not sure how I can integrate what you have suggested - ideally I need to understand if/how I can use the "SimpleDateFormat" function to return an epoch timestamp as this would mean that I wont need to re-jig any of the other code as my understanding is limited

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an example, hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you glitch - this does help with my understanding!

Answer (score 1):

First advice is to move to java8 java.time API instead of learning the broken java.date API

then do:

```
Instant i = Instant.now();
System.out.println(i.toEpochMilli());
```

in your case you can do:

```
LocalDateTime myldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-06-14 14:29:04",
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
System.out.println(myldt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli());
```

note that as soon as you play more with the api you will find more ways to achieve the same thing, at  the end you will end invoking [toEpochMilli](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--)

Comment: Thanks for your comment - the code I reference above is part of a block of code and I am not sure how I can integrate what you have suggested - ideally I need to understand if/how I can use the "SimpleDateFormat" function to return an epoch timestamp as this would mean that I wont need to re-jig any of the other code as my understanding is limited

Comment: yes. instead of using ***SimpleDateFormat***  use the ***DateTimeFormatter***

Comment: Thank you, I will have a play and see if I can literally exchange "SimpleDateFormat " for "DateTimeFormatter" in the code and use "SSS" as a formatter (?) - I am very new to java so please forgive my ignorance!

Comment: you will need java 8 to use that class

Answer (score 1):

```
    String strDate = "Jun 13 2003 23:11:52.454 UTC";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");
    ZonedDateTime     zdt  = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDate,dtf);        
    System.out.println(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());  // 1055545912454
```

Comment: Nice code, but lacking explanation. Code-only answers are seldom helpful, so please explain how you are solving the asker’s issue.

Comment: This thread could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687433/convert-a-date-format-in-epoch

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: I think op wants to get the millis from a string date

Comment: you are right... nevertheless that is not specified on the question

Comment: this is only a response for a question... it was assumed the author was taking the date from the system