# Convert a datatime in UTC to epoch time (seconds)

Tags: java, datetime

I want to convert a timestamp in UTC, e.g. *May 27, 2020, 22:35 (UTC)* to epoch seconds.  I will be hard coding the time in my code, so don't need to parse any string.  I am using the Calendar class as follows:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
calendar.set(2020, Calendar.MAY, 22, 22, 35);
calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

The epoch time is correct to the second level, but the milliseconds part seems random on every run.  Example run output:

```
Time : 1590618900110
```

Is there a way I can set the millisecond to zero in Calendar object, or a better option, possibly from the **java.time** framework?

Edit:

The following worked fine for me, since I am hardcoding the UTC time in code:

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2020-05-27T22:35:00.00Z");
long timeInMillisEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli();
```

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: java.time is the better Choice. Do not longer use the old calendar api.

Comment: [Convert a date format in epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30830088/13527856)

Comment: @MarcoLucidi Since I know the exact datetime, that solution is an overkill.  Found an easier one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

since you already know the "exact datetime" and I guess you want to avoid the parsing, you can use this [`.of()` method from `java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-java.time.ZoneOffset-), e.g.:

```
$ jshell

jshell> import java.time.*

jshell> OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of(2020, 5, 27, 22, 35, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)
odt ==> 2020-05-27T22:35Z

jshell> odt.toEpochSecond()
$14 ==> 1590618900

jshell> odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli()
$19 ==> 1590618900000
```

**edit**: rewrite following @Andreas advices

Comment: Use constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) instead of `ZoneId.of("UTC")`, which also means you should use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) instead of [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Comment: Question is asking for "epoch time (**seconds**)", so use [`offsetDateTime.toEpochSecond()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toEpochSecond--). No need to create an `Instant` first.

Comment: @Andreas it is not very clear if he wants seconds (title) or milliseconds (question body) so I left both examples